# Azure User Impersonation does not work when User/Assignment enable on the Backend App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, impersonation, azure-application-registration

I have two application registrations: one for the backend and one for the frontend.

On the backend App Reg, I have defined (exposed) a scope called `User_impersonation` like the following:

[image]

On the frontend App Reg, I have added the permissions (User_impersonation) like the following:

[image]

Also on the frontend side, I enabled user/group assignment and assigned a security group; so that only the members of that security group can access/query this frontend.

[image]

So far, when a user queries the frontend with an access token (requested from the frontend app reg); everything works fine: the frontend app reg requests an access token from the backend and forwards the request of the user.

However, when I try to enable the user/group assignment on the backend app reg (by adding the same security group); the frontend app can no longer query the backend (User_impersonation fails); like the query times out with no reply from the backend.

Can someone help me make the User_impersonation work when the group assignment is enabled on both app regs (not only the frontend). Thanks.

This is how the client/user requests access to the webapp/frontend:

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, ClientSecretCredential

authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/v2.0"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(authority=authority, exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True)
scope = "api://{frontend_clientid}/.default"
minerva_webapp_access_token = credential.get_token(scope).token
```

and this is how the webapp/frontend requests access to the backend app reg:

```py
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
    client_id=WEBAPP_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=webapp_client_secret)
scope = (                "api://{minerva_python39_backend_app_client_id}/.default".format(
                        minerva_python39_backend_app_client_id=MINERVA_PYTHON39_CLIENTID))

access_token = credential.get_token(scope).token
```

Comment: Could you include what authentication flow you are using to request access token like authorization code flow or implicit flow?

Comment: I am using Python Azure-Identity to request the access token; I included code sample in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, **client credentials** flow works **only** with permissions of
> **`Application`** type. This flow won't work with `User_impersonation` as it is **Delegated** permission.

I registered 2 applications in my Azure AD tenant same as you: one for the backend and one for the frontend.

On the **Backend** application, I defined (exposed) `User_impersonation` scope like below:

[image]

On the **Frontend** application, I added  `User_impersonation`  API permission:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using **client credentials** with same code as you like below:

```py
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
    client_id=WEBAPP_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=webapp_client_secret)
scope = (                "api://{minerva_python39_backend_app_client_id}/.default".format(
                        minerva_python39_backend_app_client_id=MINERVA_PYTHON39_CLIENTID))

access_token = credential.get_token(scope).token
print(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decode the token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), it has right **audience** in **`aud`** but missing **`scp`** claim like below:

[image]

> To make `User_impersonation` work when the group assignment is enabled on both app regs, your access token should have **`scp`** claim with that specific permission.
>
> For that, you need to use **Delegated** flows like authorization code
> flow, interactive flow, username password flow etc... for generating tokens.

In my case, I used **authorization code** flow to generate access token for which code is needed. I ran below authorization request in browser and got **code** successfully in address bar:

```http
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=<frontend_appId>
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope= api://<backend_appID>/User_impersonation
&state=12345
```

**Code:**

[image]

I ran below python code and got **access token** using authorization code flow in **response** like this:

```py
from azure.identity import AuthorizationCodeCredential

   credential = AuthorizationCodeCredential(
       tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
       client_id=WEBAPP_CLIENT_ID,
       authorization_code="<auth_code_from_above>",
       redirect_uri="https://jwt.ms",
   )

scope = ( "api://{minerva_python39_backend_app_client_id}/.default".format(
                        minerva_python39_backend_app_client_id=MINERVA_PYTHON39_CLIENTID))

access_token = credential.get_token(scope).token
print(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decode the token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), it has right **audience** in **`aud`** and **User_impersonation** permission in **`scp`** claim like below:

[image]

In your case, decode whether the token has **User_impersonation** permission in **`scp`** claim and change to **Delegated** flows for generating token to access backend as I mentioned.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it makes it more clear now. One more question, is it possible to automate the code generation using Python script (GET request); or does it to have to be made only through the browser?

Comment: AFAIK, it should be made only through browser as user need to sign in interactively.