# NodeJs AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403 (Mircosft Graph API)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I working with an MS Graph API to read a user calendar event using Lambda with NodeJs. Here is the flow of what I am doing:
First I registered an app in AAD and gave the delegated permission like

- Calendars.ReadWrite
- User.Read
  [image]

Here is the code flow:
first I am getting the access token

```
var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/af2601c4-9adasd-******-99fd-e15104d7d9fc/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      data: data(I am passing the clientid, client_secret, scope etc)
    };
```

and after that, I am trying to read the calendar event

```
try{ const response = await axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/108ca636-***-41e2-8dd5-********/events', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    });
```

but it gives me this error

```
"message": "Request failed with status code 403",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

PS: I decoded the Access token and I don't see any permission{in the above picture} I have given in the AAD to the app.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using client credentials flow but granted permissions of `Delegated` type that throws 403 error. To resolve it, you need to grant permissions of `Application` type and generate the token again

Comment: thanks @Sridevi , As there a way to do it with delegated permissions, I mean which other flow do I have to use to work with delegated permission?

Comment: To work with `Delegated` permissions, you need to use interactive flows like authorization code flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error occurred as you are using permissions of **Delegated** type that won't work with client credentials flow.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I granted **`Delegated`** permissions and used that token to fetch user's events via Postman:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/events
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to grant permissions of **Application** type and make sure to grant admin consent like this:

[image]

Now, I generated the token again using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode this token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check **`roles`** claim for permissions:

[image]

When I used this token to fetch user's events with below Graph API call, I got **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/events
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you want to work with **Delegated** permissions, make use of interactive flows like authorization code flow.

**Reference:**
[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, From what I have read and understand from the reference you provided Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 autho code flow is that it will open a web page where there will be token.
example: Once you run the server and navigate to redirect urlhttp://localhost:3000/login in your browser, it will initiate the authentication flow, and after succesful authentication, it will display the obtained access token in the browser.

what I want to streamline the authentication process (not posible with OAuth 2.0 Auth Code Flow)?
PS: Sorry this just my poor understanding

Comment: After successful authentication, it will display `code` value in browser. Use that code value to obtain token using authorisation code flow. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017669/azure-user-impersonation-does-not-work-when-user-assignment-enable-on-the-backen#77027420